# How to fix 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH` in Github Actions?

Tags: python, django, selenium, github, github-actions

I have a basic test like this:

When I locally do:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium import webdriver

class TestKundeSeite(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUp(cls):
        cls.browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'crm\tests\chromedriver.exe')

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.browser.quit()
        super().tearDownClass()

    def test_kunde_anlegen(self):
        self.browser.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/crm/kunde_anlegen'))
        vorname_input = self.browser.find_element_by_name("vorname")
        vorname_input.send_keys('Max')
        nachname_input = self.browser.find_element_by_name("nachname")
        nachname_input.send_keys('Mustermann')
        email_input = self.browser.find_element_by_name("email")
        email_input.send_keys('max@hotmail.de')
        telefon_input = self.browser.find_element_by_name("telefon")
        telefon_input.send_keys('+4917666994073')
        web_input = self.browser.find_element_by_name("web")
        web_input.send_keys('max.de')
        notiz_input = self.browser.find_element_by_name("notiz")
        notiz_input.send_keys('Beispielnotiz')
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Speichern"]').click()
```

when I do:

```
python manage.py test
```

it works fine.

But when I push it to Github, I get the following error in Github Actions

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'crm\tests\chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Still actual? Please, show full script of github-actions.

Comment: I solved the problem: in the setUp-function, I added chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')cls.browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)

Comment: Great! I'm proud of you. I found a solution without headless mode. Can add as an answer if your are interested :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'crm\tests\chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

#### Problem root cause

The problem is the exception you get tells that it can't find webdriver.
It can be solved manually but I prefer to use library [webdriver_manager](http://github.com/sergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/)

#### Solution:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager # <--- add this

class TestKundeSeite(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUp(cls):
        cls.browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()) # <--- change this
```

webdriver_manager installs by `pip install webdriver_manager`

Comment: thx bro, I already had the solution but nice answer!